# Pass a variable from one jsp to another

Tags: jsp

As a newbie struglling (again) to get a simple variaale to be accessible on more than the jsp it was created in.

I have the path to an immage file (/uploads/Test.jpg) in a var image_path = RegExp.$1 (I am not sure if this is the correct var type to use)

I then session.setAttribute("webcamfile", image_path);

I want to see / test the contents of image_path in another jsp (but just for this user) so I

String camera = request.getAttribute("webcamfile").to String();

but  webcamfile is always null whereas image_path is correct.

1st jsp

```
var image_path = RegExp.$1;
var image_path = image_url.substring(image_url.indexOf("uploads", 8));
alert(image_path);

session.setAttribute("webcamfile", image_path);
```

2nd jsp (I cannot include the first jsp because this produces multiple errors)

```
String camera = request.getSession().getAttribute("webcamfile").toString();
```

I am obviously making a number of basic mistakes, can anyone enlighten me?

I just need to share image_path between jsp's.

Regards
Active

Answer (score 0):

Since you are setting the "webcamfile" as a session attribute, it needs to be retrieved from the session scope, not request scope. So try the following:

`request.getSession().getAttribute("webcamfile").to String();`

Comment: Thanks @VHS, tried but nothing in webcamfile, do I need an Include 'first.jsp' in my second.jsp? Note that webcamfile should only be accessible by this user.

Comment: @Active, where exactly do you set the webcamfile attribute and how. Can you explain the request flow?

Comment: thanks, I have updated my original question, suspect there are fundamental mistakes.

Comment: Also, show the code of how you are including both the JSPs in the same request scope from your servlet. You can only include one jsp from the servlet doGet method but that JSP in turn can include multiple other JSPs using the `<jsp:include>` directive.

Comment: Tried <jsp:include page="first.jsp"/>  but this results in multiple Eclipse errors (undefined attribute page, file value required, missing file attribute). I am working on some exiting code which has multiple jsp's and mutiple shared variables (with no includes) and these other variables seem to work across jsp's, I dont know enough to figure out how or why.